# How to handle an error when it occurs using try catch in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, try-catch

I have this page which request a cookie value that will be stored in DepartmentId,when a cookie is not present an error occurs.Now I want to catch that error so that it doesn't crash my server. I've used a plain try catch statement,now I need to know if there is any other ways to catch the error here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nvc.AddFromQueryString(Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("DepartmentID", HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["DepartmentId"].Value, Request.QueryString);

        StoredProcedureCaller spc = new StoredProcedureCaller();
        spc.Execute(nvc, Resources.StoredProcedureDefinitions.GetCurrentDowntimeEventForDepartment, Resources.ConnectionStrings.HestoNew);

        Response.Write(spc.ToString("json"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Exception catch", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Your code is already catching any exceptions.

Comment: Catching exceptions is a costly way of controlling program flow. You can just as easily check for the existance of the cookie value before trying to use it and control flow that way. More better. ;)

Comment: Check whether `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["DepartmentId"]` is returning null ? Is that the question is all about?

Comment: Like can I use InvalidCastExcpection instead of Exception only if there is no cookie present

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes how would I do that?

Comment: `var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["DepartmentId"]; if(cookie!=null){//use cookie.Value}`

Answer (score 1):

Another way of checking if it is null could be to do something like this:

```
if (cookie != null) 
{
    //do something
}

else 
{
    //notify that the cookie is null
}
```